# How to get all the objects in this data model?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I need to take all the Model Objects in this kind of data structure below.

```js
const PRODUCTS = [
    {
        brand: 'Audi',
        allSeries: {
            serie: 'A3',
            allModels: [
                { model: 'A3 1.5 Sportback' },
                { model: 'A3 2.0 TDI' }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        brand: 'Volkswagen',
        allSeries: {
            serie: 'Golf',
            allModels: [
                { model: 'Golf 1.5' },
                { model: 'Golf 2.0' }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

So I need all the model objects in one array pushed like `[{model:'Golf 1.5}, {...}, {...}]` this data structure.

Comment: Have you tried to use a loop? Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple enough to do with the array `map()` method. Let me know if this works for you:

```js
const PRODUCTS = [{ brand: 'Audi', allSeries: { serie: 'A3', allModels: [ { model: 'A3 1.5 Sportback' }, { model: 'A3 2.0 TDI' } ] } },{ brand: 'Volkswagen', allSeries: { serie: 'Golf', allModels: [ { model: 'Golf 1.5' }, { model: 'Golf 2.0' } ] } }];

const models = PRODUCTS.flatMap(product => product.allSeries.allModels);

console.log(models);
```

Comment: Actually allSeries is an array of objects too. I edited my code a few minutes ago.allSeries is not an object.

Comment: You mention `map` in the text but use `flatMap` in your code?

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks a lot !! Appreciated. I took every model in 2 steps.                      const series = allProducts.flatMap((item)=> {
            return item.allSeries;
    });

    const models = series.flatMap((item)=>item.allModels);

Comment: Ah yes, I originally used `.map(…).flat()` but shortened it to `.flatMap(…)` to be more concise.